# Using 'gitweb' style shows all branches. Can I show only desired number of branches?

Tags: mercurial, gitweb, hgweb

When Using 'gitweb' style for hgweb on a page I can see planty of branches, for example if I have 1000 of them - all are shown.

I tried setting:

[defaults]
branches = -a

in global hgrc file but it doesn't effect the web view. My guess is it is related to 'gitweb' style template's files.

Is there any easy way of limitating the number of branches shown in a web view?

mercurial 1.0.1-5.1~bpo40+1

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do it. I'm not even sure the web templating language currently used can allow it.

The template file can be found [here](http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew/file/36a65283c3af/mercurial/templates/gitweb/branches.tmpl).